# How to import sql,gz file into my databases

Tags: mysql, database, gzip

I want to import a sql.gz file into mySQL database, and I follow the instruction on Google. But it just failed. I really can't figure out why. So I came here to ask for help.

#### Here are my query commands:

```
 zcat qmdb__v1_3__102019.sql.gz | mysql -u root -p 123456 meterial;
```

```
 gunzip < F:/qmdb__v1_3__102019.sql.gz | mysql -u root -p meterial;
```

```
 gunzip < qmdb__v1_3__102019.sql.gz | mysql -u root -p meterial
```

Three types all failed.

The error message:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'gunzip < qmdb__v1_3__102019.sql.gz | mysql -u root -p meterial' at line 1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoSXA.png)

I think my file path isn't wrong.

Comment: Try: remove the space betqeen -p and the password and test obly the mysql part to see if you can login into the database

Comment: Also it can be possible that you must spezify the databse wirh the -D option. If this is not in the sql file

Comment: I'd say you found shell commands in Google and you are trying to execute them in a SQL client. Additionally, zcat and gunzip do not come with Windows, you need to download and install them or use Linux (e.g. WSL). Or simply unzip the file first!

Comment: OK, Thanks a lot. I mistake OS....Now when I unzip my file ,finally succeed.....